# Add folder if it doesn't exist and add file in Google Drive in Python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I'm trying to create a folder if it doesn't exist, and then add a file under that directory. The script below runs without errors and seems successful, however no folders are created and no files added to the gdrive.

def SyncDrive(newFile, parentFolderId, subFolder):
   #auth stuff here
    SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
    credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name('myserver.json', SCOPES)
    http_auth = credentials.authorize(Http())
    DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=http_auth)

`# create subfolder if it doesn't exist
    subdir_metadata = {
      'name': subFolder,
      'mimeType': 'application/vnd.google-apps.folder',
      'parents':[{'id': parentFolderId}]
    }

    result = DRIVE.files().create(body=subdir_metadata,fields='id').execute()
    subdir_id = result.get('id')

    file_metadata = {
      'name': newFile,
      'parents': [{'id': subdir_id}]
    }

    result = DRIVE.files().create(body=file_metadata, media_body=file_path, fields='id').execute()`

Comment: welcome to SO. "This does not seem to work" doesn't give nearly enough information for anybody to answer your question. You need to include exactly what is happening, vs what you expect to happen and any error messages along the way and the values of all responses.

Comment: There are no errors. It seems to run successfully, but it  just does not create any folders or add the files to the drive.

Comment: You need to include exactly what is happening, vs what you expect to happen and any error messages along the way ****and the values of all responses***
How do you know it didn't create the folder? What steps/tests did you do to see the folder was missing?